# Does Bill Gaede's needle experiment debunk the debunks the entirety of quantum and relativity as he claims?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What are the flaws in Bill Gaede's needle experiment? In his paper "An Alternative to Waves and Wave-Packets" he claims by replicating both the double-slit and gravitational lensing without use of walls concludes that the reification of space-time was completely unnecessary, nor is light a stream of discrete bouncing balls.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a few years since I've heard that name. As I understand it, his claimed results of his thought experiment are at variance with what actually happens if you do the experiment. Even if his claimed results for his thought experiment with a needle and water waves were true, one cannot "debunk" *any* description of quantum physics with this reasoning because hydrodynamic waves in a ripple tank diffractive around a needle are *not* a quantum system. They are at best an analogy, and if we get insight into quantum systems from them, the predictions we make about quantum systems from these insights must be tested experimentally with the actual quantum system.

He makes a big deal about "reification", claiming physicists confuse their theories and models with reality. If that were so, the physics discipline would not be employing any experimental physicists. The fact that physics always returns to experiment to test theoretical predictions shows that enough people understand the difference that, as a group, physicists are not hindered by a fallacy of reification. If I recall correctly, he attacks the use of the spacetime manifold particularly vigorously in this way: even if there were no experiments, the fact that theorists are working on quantum gravity shows that physics knows that there is more to reality than simply geometry on a spacetime manifold: quantum gravity could be described as the endeavor to discover the underlying machinery within the reality of spacetime that explains how our classical, "reified" geometry on spacetime manifold models are remarkably good at foretelling experimental results.